# Anchor tag change image on hover and active

Tags: html, css, anchor

I am trying to change the anchor tag image on hover and active, but it is not working.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3><a href="" runat="server" id="aCollection">test</a></h3>
        <div class="acsection" runat="server" id="divCollection">
            <ul>
                <li runat="server" id="collectionmenu1"><a href="1.aspx">page-1</a></li>
                <li runat="server" id="collectionmenu2"><a href="2.aspx">page-2</a></li>
                <li runat="server" id="collectionmenu3"><a href="3.aspx">page-3</a></li>
                <li runat="server" id="collectionmenu4"><a href="4.aspx">page-4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="5.aspx">Group</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="6.aspx">Send</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="7.aspx">contact</a></h3>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#aCollection
{
    background-image: url(images/collection.jpg);
}

#aCollection:hover
{
    background-image: url(images/collection_hover.jpg);
}

#aCollection:active
{
    background-image: url(images/collection_active.jpg);
}
```

Comment: i was able to fix it by changing the attributes in the codebehind.

Answer (score 9):

Try this one. it's working :).
just add src= for the hover image and when the mouse out also add src=.

```
<a href="#"><img src="blah.jpg" onMouseOver=src="blah-hover.jpg" onMouseOut=src="blah.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

A tag is a inline element. You need a block element.

```
#aCollection {
     display: block;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background: url('../images/image.jpg') no-repeat top left;
}
#aCollection:hover {
     background-image: url('../images/image_hover.jpg');
}
#aCollection:active {
     background-image: url('../images/image_active.jpg');
}
```

Comment: try background: url('images/your_image.jpg') no-repeat top left; and also check if your path is correct (you might need ../images)

Comment: yes your suggestion works for hover. but still the active is not working

Comment: it should work the same for hover and active. Check if the image path is correct.

Comment: yes the image is in right folder. even if i use the same image as hover it is not working for active

Comment: updated my answer, try changing id="aCollection" to class="aCollection" and drop the # in the css

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your URLs with quotes,

```
**stylesheet code**
#aCollection
{
    background-image: url('images/collection.jpg');
}
#aCollection:hover
{
    background-image: url('images/collection_hover.jpg');
}

#aCollection:active
{
    background-image: url('images/collection_active.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that your CSS is targeting actual image URIs? In other words if your CSS is part of the HTML document itself then your images should be in a folder called `images` relative to the current HTML document.

However if this CSS is part of an external stylesheet which is located in lets say the `css` folder you need to use a relative path which will go one level up to access the images.

```
css
    -> stylesheet.css
images
    -> collection.jpg

page.html
```

Your stylesheet should contain `background-image` rules in the following format

```
background-image: url('../images/collection.jpg');
```

BTW, using separate images for what you are trying to achieve is not such a good idea for at least two reasons:

1. Every image is an additional browser request - too many requests can clutter the initial page display
2. Additional images are loaded only on request (when you move your mouse over the link, click it etc.) which will produce an ugly flickering effect in time the requested image is actually loaded

Therefore use [**CSS sprites**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) to eliminate both of these problems.